# Barcode not printing whole reference number when passed thru $variable

Tags: php, sql

I am using this barcode.php barcode generator and having a problem displaying my barcode when it get passed thru a variable. however if I use it directly sample - `img src="/barcode.php?text=202205-000012" alt="Reference Number"` it gets displayed perfectly and can be read by the barcode scanner provided. the truncated one does not read and looks a bit stretched

here is the sample of the :

1. reference number in text format
2. reference number when passed thru variable
3. reference number when I tried to make it bigger (thought maybe the other parts are hidden)
4. and the reference number which is hardcoded

[image: barcode samples]

as you can see in the 4th example the hardcoded one is the correct barcode. what might be the problem.

I've Already tried this format with brackets

```
<img class="img-responsive" alt="testing" src="barcode.php?text="{{ $docNumber }} width="450" height="100"/>
```

and this format with the dot

```
<img class="img-responsive" alt="testing" src="barcode.php?text=" . $docNumber  width="450" height="100"/>
```

they both generate truncated image of the barcode

[image: barcode samples]

Here is my barcode number passed thru variable `$docnumber` which comes from our sqlserver (our site is local only to our employees and will be used by the company)

```
//Read RMS DB
if( $conCore2 === false )
        {
         echo "Could not connect to Core2 Server.\n";
         die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true));
    }else{
        try {
            //get Reference No with format 000000 and Current Server Date
            $sql = "SELECT concat(FORMAT(GetDate(),'yyyyMM-'),REPLACE(STR(CAST(COUNT(*) AS INT) + 1,6), SPACE(1), '0')) AS Count,getdate() as creationdate FROM [dbo].[tbl_Documents]";
            $resultset = sqlsrv_query($conCore2, $sql);

            $row = sqlsrv_fetch_array($resultset, SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC);
            $docNumber= $row['Count'];
            $creationdate= $row['creationdate']->format('m/d/Y');

            //close the connection and release resources
             sqlsrv_close($conCore2);
            
        }

        //catch exception
        catch(Exception $e) {
            echo 'Message: ' .$e->getMessage();
        }
    }
```

here is my code for displaying barcode as seen in the example

```
<div class="col d-flex justify-content-end align-items-center" >
            
                    <h6 style="font-family: 'Karla', sans-serif;">Barcode:</h6> 
                                                                   
                       
                         
                         <div  style="width: 450px; height: 100px;" class="border" id="bcode">
                         <?php echo $docNumber; ?>
                         <h1><img alt="testing" src="barcode.php?text="<?php echo isset($docNumber) ? $docNumber :'' ?>  width="240" height="80"/></h1>
                            <h1><img class="img-responsive" alt="testing" src="barcode.php?text="{{ $docNumber }} width="450" height="100"/></h1>
                            <h1><img alt="testing" src="barcode.php?text=202205-00011" width="240" height="80"/></h1>
                            
                        </div> 
                   
            </div>
```

Here is the barcode.php I am currently using

```
<?php

/*
 *  Author  David S. Tufts
 *  Company davidscotttufts.com
 *    
 *  Date:   05/25/2003
 *  Usage:  <img src="/barcode.php?text=testing" alt="testing" />
 */

// For demonstration purposes, get pararameters that are passed in through $_GET or set to the default value
$filepath = (isset($_GET["filepath"])?$_GET["filepath"]:"");
$text = (isset($_GET["text"])?$_GET["text"]:"0");
$size = (isset($_GET["size"])?$_GET["size"]:"20");
$orientation = (isset($_GET["orientation"])?$_GET["orientation"]:"horizontal");
$code_type = (isset($_GET["codetype"])?$_GET["codetype"]:"code128");
$print = (isset($_GET["print"])&&$_GET["print"]=='true'?true:false);
$sizefactor = (isset($_GET["sizefactor"])?$_GET["sizefactor"]:"1");

// This function call can be copied into your project and can be made from anywhere in your code
barcode( $filepath, $text, $size, $orientation, $code_type, $print, $sizefactor );

function barcode( $filepath="", $text="0", $size="20", $orientation="horizontal", $code_type="code128", $print=false, $SizeFactor=1 ) {
    $code_string = "";
    // Translate the $text into barcode the correct $code_type
    if ( in_array(strtolower($code_type), array("code128", "code128b")) ) {
        $chksum = 104;
        // Must not change order of array elements as the checksum depends on the array's key to validate final code
        $code_array = array(" "=>"212222","!"=>"222122","\""=>"222221","#"=>"121223","$"=>"121322","%"=>"131222","&"=>"122213","'"=>"122312","("=>"132212",")"=>"221213","*"=>"221312","+"=>"231212",","=>"112232","-"=>"122132","."=>"122231","/"=>"113222","0"=>"123122","1"=>"123221","2"=>"223211","3"=>"221132","4"=>"221231","5"=>"213212","6"=>"223112","7"=>"312131","8"=>"311222","9"=>"321122",":"=>"321221",";"=>"312212","<"=>"322112","="=>"322211",">"=>"212123","?"=>"212321","@"=>"232121","A"=>"111323","B"=>"131123","C"=>"131321","D"=>"112313","E"=>"132113","F"=>"132311","G"=>"211313","H"=>"231113","I"=>"231311","J"=>"112133","K"=>"112331","L"=>"132131","M"=>"113123","N"=>"113321","O"=>"133121","P"=>"313121","Q"=>"211331","R"=>"231131","S"=>"213113","T"=>"213311","U"=>"213131","V"=>"311123","W"=>"311321","X"=>"331121","Y"=>"312113","Z"=>"312311","["=>"332111","\\"=>"314111","]"=>"221411","^"=>"431111","_"=>"111224","\`"=>"111422","a"=>"121124","b"=>"121421","c"=>"141122","d"=>"141221","e"=>"112214","f"=>"112412","g"=>"122114","h"=>"122411","i"=>"142112","j"=>"142211","k"=>"241211","l"=>"221114","m"=>"413111","n"=>"241112","o"=>"134111","p"=>"111242","q"=>"121142","r"=>"121241","s"=>"114212","t"=>"124112","u"=>"124211","v"=>"411212","w"=>"421112","x"=>"421211","y"=>"212141","z"=>"214121","{"=>"412121","|"=>"111143","}"=>"111341","~"=>"131141","DEL"=>"114113","FNC 3"=>"114311","FNC 2"=>"411113","SHIFT"=>"411311","CODE C"=>"113141","FNC 4"=>"114131","CODE A"=>"311141","FNC 1"=>"411131","Start A"=>"211412","Start B"=>"211214","Start C"=>"211232","Stop"=>"2331112");
        $code_keys = array_keys($code_array);
        $code_values = array_flip($code_keys);
        for ( $X = 1; $X <= strlen($text); $X++ ) {
            $activeKey = substr( $text, ($X-1), 1);
            $code_string .= $code_array[$activeKey];
            $chksum=($chksum + ($code_values[$activeKey] * $X));
        }
        $code_string .= $code_array[$code_keys[($chksum - (intval($chksum / 103) * 103))]];

        $code_string = "211214" . $code_string . "2331112";
    } elseif ( strtolower($code_type) == "code128a" ) {
        $chksum = 103;
        $text = strtoupper($text); // Code 128A doesn't support lower case
        // Must not change order of array elements as the checksum depends on the array's key to validate final code
        $code_array = array(" "=>"212222","!"=>"222122","\""=>"222221","#"=>"121223","$"=>"121322","%"=>"131222","&"=>"122213","'"=>"122312","("=>"132212",")"=>"221213","*"=>"221312","+"=>"231212",","=>"112232","-"=>"122132","."=>"122231","/"=>"113222","0"=>"123122","1"=>"123221","2"=>"223211","3"=>"221132","4"=>"221231","5"=>"213212","6"=>"223112","7"=>"312131","8"=>"311222","9"=>"321122",":"=>"321221",";"=>"312212","<"=>"322112","="=>"322211",">"=>"212123","?"=>"212321","@"=>"232121","A"=>"111323","B"=>"131123","C"=>"131321","D"=>"112313","E"=>"132113","F"=>"132311","G"=>"211313","H"=>"231113","I"=>"231311","J"=>"112133","K"=>"112331","L"=>"132131","M"=>"113123","N"=>"113321","O"=>"133121","P"=>"313121","Q"=>"211331","R"=>"231131","S"=>"213113","T"=>"213311","U"=>"213131","V"=>"311123","W"=>"311321","X"=>"331121","Y"=>"312113","Z"=>"312311","["=>"332111","\\"=>"314111","]"=>"221411","^"=>"431111","_"=>"111224","NUL"=>"111422","SOH"=>"121124","STX"=>"121421","ETX"=>"141122","EOT"=>"141221","ENQ"=>"112214","ACK"=>"112412","BEL"=>"122114","BS"=>"122411","HT"=>"142112","LF"=>"142211","VT"=>"241211","FF"=>"221114","CR"=>"413111","SO"=>"241112","SI"=>"134111","DLE"=>"111242","DC1"=>"121142","DC2"=>"121241","DC3"=>"114212","DC4"=>"124112","NAK"=>"124211","SYN"=>"411212","ETB"=>"421112","CAN"=>"421211","EM"=>"212141","SUB"=>"214121","ESC"=>"412121","FS"=>"111143","GS"=>"111341","RS"=>"131141","US"=>"114113","FNC 3"=>"114311","FNC 2"=>"411113","SHIFT"=>"411311","CODE C"=>"113141","CODE B"=>"114131","FNC 4"=>"311141","FNC 1"=>"411131","Start A"=>"211412","Start B"=>"211214","Start C"=>"211232","Stop"=>"2331112");
        $code_keys = array_keys($code_array);
        $code_values = array_flip($code_keys);
        for ( $X = 1; $X <= strlen($text); $X++ ) {
            $activeKey = substr( $text, ($X-1), 1);
            $code_string .= $code_array[$activeKey];
            $chksum=($chksum + ($code_values[$activeKey] * $X));
        }
        $code_string .= $code_array[$code_keys[($chksum - (intval($chksum / 103) * 103))]];

        $code_string = "211412" . $code_string . "2331112";
    } elseif ( strtolower($code_type) == "code39" ) {
        $code_array = array("0"=>"111221211","1"=>"211211112","2"=>"112211112","3"=>"212211111","4"=>"111221112","5"=>"211221111","6"=>"112221111","7"=>"111211212","8"=>"211211211","9"=>"112211211","A"=>"211112112","B"=>"112112112","C"=>"212112111","D"=>"111122112","E"=>"211122111","F"=>"112122111","G"=>"111112212","H"=>"211112211","I"=>"112112211","J"=>"111122211","K"=>"211111122","L"=>"112111122","M"=>"212111121","N"=>"111121122","O"=>"211121121","P"=>"112121121","Q"=>"111111222","R"=>"211111221","S"=>"112111221","T"=>"111121221","U"=>"221111112","V"=>"122111112","W"=>"222111111","X"=>"121121112","Y"=>"221121111","Z"=>"122121111","-"=>"121111212","."=>"221111211"," "=>"122111211","$"=>"121212111","/"=>"121211121","+"=>"121112121","%"=>"111212121","*"=>"121121211");

        // Convert to uppercase
        $upper_text = strtoupper($text);

        for ( $X = 1; $X<=strlen($upper_text); $X++ ) {
            $code_string .= $code_array[substr( $upper_text, ($X-1), 1)] . "1";
        }

        $code_string = "1211212111" . $code_string . "121121211";
    } elseif ( strtolower($code_type) == "code25" ) {
        $code_array1 = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0");
        $code_array2 = array("3-1-1-1-3","1-3-1-1-3","3-3-1-1-1","1-1-3-1-3","3-1-3-1-1","1-3-3-1-1","1-1-1-3-3","3-1-1-3-1","1-3-1-3-1","1-1-3-3-1");

        for ( $X = 1; $X <= strlen($text); $X++ ) {
            for ( $Y = 0; $Y < count($code_array1); $Y++ ) {
                if ( substr($text, ($X-1), 1) == $code_array1[$Y] )
                    $temp[$X] = $code_array2[$Y];
            }
        }

        for ( $X=1; $X<=strlen($text); $X+=2 ) {
            if ( isset($temp[$X]) && isset($temp[($X + 1)]) ) {
                $temp1 = explode( "-", $temp[$X] );
                $temp2 = explode( "-", $temp[($X + 1)] );
                for ( $Y = 0; $Y < count($temp1); $Y++ )
                    $code_string .= $temp1[$Y] . $temp2[$Y];
            }
        }

        $code_string = "1111" . $code_string . "311";
    } elseif ( strtolower($code_type) == "codabar" ) {
        $code_array1 = array("1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","0","-","$",":","/",".","+","A","B","C","D");
        $code_array2 = array("1111221","1112112","2211111","1121121","2111121","1211112","1211211","1221111","2112111","1111122","1112211","1122111","2111212","2121112","2121211","1121212","1122121","1212112","1112122","1112221");

        // Convert to uppercase
        $upper_text = strtoupper($text);

        for ( $X = 1; $X<=strlen($upper_text); $X++ ) {
            for ( $Y = 0; $Y<count($code_array1); $Y++ ) {
                if ( substr($upper_text, ($X-1), 1) == $code_array1[$Y] )
                    $code_string .= $code_array2[$Y] . "1";
            }
        }
        $code_string = "11221211" . $code_string . "1122121";
    }

    // Pad the edges of the barcode
    $code_length = 20;
    if ($print) {
        $text_height = 30;
    } else {
        $text_height = 0;
    }
    
    for ( $i=1; $i <= strlen($code_string); $i++ ){
        $code_length = $code_length + (integer)(substr($code_string,($i-1),1));
        }

    if ( strtolower($orientation) == "horizontal" ) {
        $img_width = $code_length*$SizeFactor;
        $img_height = $size;
    } else {
        $img_width = $size;
        $img_height = $code_length*$SizeFactor;
    }

    $image = imagecreate($img_width, $img_height + $text_height);
    $black = imagecolorallocate ($image, 0, 0, 0);
    $white = imagecolorallocate ($image, 255, 255, 255);

    imagefill( $image, 0, 0, $white );
    if ( $print ) {
        imagestring($image, 5, 31, $img_height, $text, $black );
    }

    $location = 10;
    for ( $position = 1 ; $position <= strlen($code_string); $position++ ) {
        $cur_size = $location + ( substr($code_string, ($position-1), 1) );
        if ( strtolower($orientation) == "horizontal" )
            imagefilledrectangle( $image, $location*$SizeFactor, 0, $cur_size*$SizeFactor, $img_height, ($position % 2 == 0 ? $white : $black) );
        else
            imagefilledrectangle( $image, 0, $location*$SizeFactor, $img_width, $cur_size*$SizeFactor, ($position % 2 == 0 ? $white : $black) );
        $location = $cur_size;
    }
    
    // Draw barcode to the screen or save in a file
    if ( $filepath=="" ) {
        header ('Content-type: image/png');
        imagepng($image);
        imagedestroy($image);
    } else {
        imagepng($image,$filepath);
        imagedestroy($image);       
    }
}

?>
```

I am new to php/css so my knowledge is a bit limited but I can understand the basics
I already tried using a font to display barcode but the only problem is when I am printing the barcode it gets previewed as text only instead of barcode font. so I used this image generating barcode generator instead but is having trouble with generating the barcode when passed thru variable.

UPDATE:
as commented by Anthony thompson.
I did not know that my code is outside the src attribute
this code he suggested did the trick.

```
<img class="img-responsive" alt="testing" src="barcode.php?text=<?php echo $docNumber; ?>"  width="450" height="100"/>
```

Comment: `<img class="img-responsive" alt="testing" src="barcode.php?text=<?php echo $docNumber; ?>"  width="450" height="100"/>`

Comment: Notice the code is now inside the src attribute. Your example has it outside the src attribute

Comment: @AntonyThompson it worked wonders thank you very much!. can you post this. its been bugging me for a week.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<img class="img-responsive" alt="testing" src="barcode.php?text=<?php echo $docNumber; ?>"  width="450" height="100"/>
```

You needed to move the php inside the src attribute.